# You Cannot Destroy Me. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

This is just a simple riddle I thought of just now!

> You may make me, but you cannot destroy me.
>
> You can see through anything with my help.
>
> When I'm (really) big and black, nobody and nothing can escape from me.
>
> I'm not used very frequently.
>
> Sometimes, I make objects unusable.

**Who/What am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I expect that you're a

> hole!

You may make me but you cannot destroy me.

> You can cut or drill (or many other verbs) holes into things, but once they're there you cannot destroy them - fill them or patch them, maybe, but you can never destroy what's not there.

You can see through anything with my help.

> Put a hole in it and you can see through it!

When I'm (really) big and black, nobody and nothing can escape from me.

> This is what really gave it away for me. This is of course referencing [black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole).

I'm not used very frequently.

> *(from PirateSoul)* There isn't a lot you can do with a hole, other than fill it; therefore, you don't use them very frequently.

Sometimes, I make objects unusable.

> Some things can't be used if there are holes in them. Clothes come to mind as an example, but a larger scale example could be a boat! The options here are limitless (to an extent).

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds!

Comment: But....I can 'destroy' you. I just fill you in with something.

Comment: @MarkN You cannot completely destroy a hole

Comment: @SharadGautam, You can with some. If i dig a hole in the sand at a beach, then overfill it with sand again. Then there is no hole, it was 'destroyed'.

Comment: @MarkN We're talking about hole in general, suppose you take an amorphous substance and make a hole in it. You cannot completely fill it!

Comment: Any ideas on the "I'm not used very frequently" line? I'm at a loss...

Comment: @BaileyM Maybe it has something to do with a hole being nothing, you can for example not pick it up and place it somewhere else, the only thing you can do with it, is fill it? just a random thought process :P

Comment: I guess probably since you don't go around drilling holes in everything.

Comment: @PirateSoul You are right

Comment: But we CAN pick up and move a hole! (Albeit indirectly) For example, if we pick up a donut and move it, have we not also indirectly picked up and moved the donut hole? We haven't made any NEW holes, but the hole remains there...

Comment: @Aify makes sense BUT when did I object on moving holes??

Comment: @SharadGautam You said PirateSoul was right, but PirateSoul says you can't pick up a hole and put it somewhere else.

Comment: But in general, you cannot pick a hole except for a donut and a few other cases- *"Exceptions are always there."*

Comment: I think black holes are very very small, no? Like singularity-sized.

Comment: @Daniel: Depends on the black hole. Some are the size of planets, while others are the size of marbles.

Comment: @Daniel Black holes contain a singularity, however The size of a black hole, as determined by the radius of the event horizon, or Schwarzschild radius, is roughly proportional to the mass. - Wikipedia.

Comment: @MarkN "roughly proportional"? It's *directly* proportional.

Comment: @Samuel - Wikipedia at its finest.

Comment: Hey, the black hole hint gave it away for me, too!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a

> black hole!

*You may make me but you cannot destroy me.*

> People, can create black holes, but cannot destroy them. ( Look up the large hadron collider)

*You can see through anything with my help.*

> As suggested by Samuel, gravitational lensing is one way in which black holes allow us to see things. Because they are very heavy and dense, they bend space-time. This means if a planet or a star is not visible to us, black holes can bend light so that it can be seen by us.

*When I'm (really)big black, nobody and nothing can escape from me.*

> Black holes are big and black. Nothing can escape them, not even light.

*I'm not used very frequently.*

> People do not use black holes in their day-to-day lives.

*Sometimes, I make object unusable*

> Anything which enters a black hole will be stretched to a great extent and will be rendered useless. ( this information is from one of Vsauce's videos on black holes)

Comment: Good point. I cannot even remember the last time I used a black hole!  :)

Comment: For the last point, throw your phone into a black hole and tell me if it's still usable! (PS: no nokia, don't cheat)

Comment: For point two, you might try [gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens).

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a

> Plastic bag(polythene  cover).

You may make me, but you cannot destroy me.

> We make it but cant be destroyed by us.

You can see through anything with my help.

> plastic covers are see through

When I'm (really) big and black, nobody and nothing can escape from me.

> Big and black covers when sealed does not allow anything out.

I'm not used very frequently.

> These days we try to use bio degradable bags.

Sometimes, I make objects unusable.

> objects that are inside it cannot be used.

Comment: Its not biodegradable.In that sense, Does that not mean it cannot be destroyed?